# Filezilla FTPS server on Windows Server 2003 - can't find a client to map a drive to this

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp, ftps

I'm running an FTPS server on Windows Server 2003 (Filezilla Server). I want to map a network drive from my PC to the server, but most of the solutions are shown as SFTP. Those that aren't won't take my self-signed cert.

Ideas?

Comment: Use something other then ftp/sftp?  Maybe webdav?

Comment: @Caveatrob Did you find a useful answer? If so, marking it helps future readers.

Comment: I wasn't able to get anything to work with FTPS on my server (Filezilla), so I stuck with FTP clients. I'll likely try to move to SFTP in the future since solutions seem a little more workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client PC is Windows and both the server and client are running NetBEUI, then it's rather simple:

1. Click the "Map Network Drive" button in Explorer
2. On the "What network folder would you like to map?" page, click the link that says "Connect to a website that you can use to store your documents and pictures."
3. Select "Choose a custom network location" and in the "Internet or network address:" field type the ftp address. E.g. ftp://winserver/directory.
4. You can choose to log on anonymously or use a specific username and password.

Now, if you want to map a drive letter to a FTP directory, you'll need a third party tool. One can also perform the same trick using `NET USE`. You'll need to modify your LMHOSTS file. [More information here](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/ftp/how-can-i-map-to-an-ftp-server-as-a-drive-).

Comment: Tried this with standard network drive mapping within the VPN and it worked, though slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Novell has a now inactive application/driver by the name of Netdrive which will connect to a FTP server and present a drive letter to that connection.

http://www.novell.com/documentation/oes/pdfdoc/netdrive/netdrive.pdf

Netdrive itself is a little bit hard to find on the Novell site and its licensing is not necessarily clear these days.